# i want to crop a image like oval shape. i am working on ionic framework based application. is there any Cordova plugin is there?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework

i am working on ionic framework based application

Comment: @Duncan C you getting my question?

Comment: Were not a human google. Google -> try -> ask

Comment: is there any idea for that please let us know. it would be very gratfull for me.

Comment: THIS ISNT A QUESTION FOR SO. 1. Google 2. Try it yourself, if you get stuck ask here, 3. if you arent able to achieve sth and dont want to learn it , pay a developer.

Comment: actually bro i tried before 1  week

Answer (score 1):

I have a demo project called [**CropImg**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/CropImg) that demonstrates cropping an image based on a user-selected rectangle. My app crops to an oval. It's written in Objective-C, but the technique is the same.

I know exactly zero about Ionic, so I can't help you there.

The abstract shapes you show in your image would be more complicated. You would need to create an editor that let the user draw those more complex shapes. I suggest looking into Catmull-Rom splines. Those are curved shapes that go through all the control points (Bezier paths, the usual curve used in computer Graphics, have control points that do not lie on the curve and they are not super-intuitive to set up.)

Erica Sadun's excellent iOS Developer's cookbook series has a receipe that shows how to create Catmull-Rom splines

### EDIT:

Actually, looking closely at the 3rd frame in your image, it appears there are Bezier control points on the image, so maybe you DO want bezier curves. Creating a UI for letting the user draw a multi-part cubic bezier curve is going to be quite a bit of work.

Comment: Duncan can you have any demo exactly like this?

Comment: no worry is ios or ionic.

Comment: @Anand Patel: Again: Duncan was very friendly and provided code, without beeing paid. Its not his job to write your app. Do it on your own, we will help you (help != doing everything)

Comment: @Jonasw please do your work. i am not here to talk with you .

Comment: No, Johnty, I don't have "any demo exactly like this". I tend to agree with Jonas. We'll point you in the right direction, but you have a specific need for your application and it's your job to meet that need. I'd be happy to develop your app for you, as work for hire.

Comment: What happened to the sample image that was originally part of your question?